# Laravel: How to Get Current Route Name? (v5 ... v7)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-6

In Laravel v4 I was able to get the current route name using...

```php
Route::currentRouteName()
```

How can I do it in **Laravel v5** and **Laravel v6**?

Comment: which namespace should i use to find route name? i have used  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route but  result is null.

Comment: That is the correct class. Your route has probably no name assigned. Note that the route name and the URI is not the same.

Comment: Here is right answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397487/get-current-path-outside-of-route

Comment: Why would you need it?

Answer (score 598, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

or

```
\Request::route()->getName()
```

from v5.1

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
$currentPath= Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
```

**Laravel v5.2**

```
Route::currentRouteName(); //use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Or if you need the action name

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
```

[Laravel 5.2 route documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

**Retrieving The Request URI**

The path method returns the request's URI. So, if the incoming request is targeted at `http://example.com/foo/bar`, the path method will return `foo/bar`:

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

The `is` method allows you to verify that the incoming request URI matches a given pattern. You may use the `*` character as a wildcard when utilizing this method:

```
if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
    //
}
```

To get the full URL, not just the path info, you may use the url method on the request instance:

```
$url = $request->url();
```

**Laravel v5.3 ... v5.8**

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

[Laravel 5.3 route documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

**Laravel v6.x...7.x**

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

** Current as of Nov 11th 2019 - version 6.5 **

[Laravel 6.x route documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

There is an option to use request to get route

```
$request->route()->getName();
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to filter this for instance if one only wants to print in the view api routes `api/...`

Comment: `Route::currentRouteName();` perfect :)

Comment: `$request::route()->getName()` if you're already using the $request, or you can use the global helper `request()::route()->getName()`.

Comment: @Daniel Dewhurst: Maybe it works on v < 5.7, but with v5.7 you must not use it statically, instead `request()->route()->getName()` is the way to go.

Comment: Using the `request()` helper function is particularly useful in views.  `request()->route()->getName()` is the best option.

Comment: `request()->routeIs('route.name')` latest way

Comment: There is also the `Route::is('admin.*')` that checks if the route name matches the given patterns.

Comment: agree with @DanielDewhurst
you can check all the method in here `Illuminate/Routing/Route`

Comment: I have used all 3 solutions in Laravel 8 version and none of them are working. // echo $route = Route::current(); 
        echo $name = Route::currentRouteName();
        echo $action = Route::currentRouteAction();

Answer (score 43):

Using Laravel 5.1, you can use

```
\Request::route()->getName()
```

Comment: this also works when you put it on the view as ```{{ route(\Request::route()->getName()) }}``` . Thanks so much!

Answer (score 29):

Found a way to find the current route name works for  laravel **v5** , **v5.1.28** and **v5.2.10**

Namespace

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

and

```
$currentPath= Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
```

For Laravel laravel **v5.3** you can just use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::currentRouteName();
```

Comment: @Jonathan I believe it's always better to use the full namespace in order to avoid any potential conflict.

Comment: any sugestion for laravel 8?

Answer (score 27):

If you want to select menu on multiple routes you may do like this:

```
<li class="{{ (Request::is('products/*') || Request::is('products') || Request::is('product/*') ? 'active' : '') }}"><a href="{{url('products')}}"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i>&nbsp; Products</a></li>
```

Or if you want to select just single menu you may simply do like this:

```
<li class="{{ (Request::is('/users') ? 'active' : '') }}"><a href="{{url('/')}}"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Users</a></li>
```

Also tested in **Laravel 5.2**

Hope this help someone.

Comment: also tested in Laravel 5.3

Comment: also tested in Laravel 7.5.2

Comment: tested in Laravel 5.7

Comment: This is the easiest way and it still works under Laravel 9.1 Thanks

Answer (score 25):

If you need **url**, not **route name**, you do not need to use/require any other classes:

```
url()->current();
```

Comment: This returns an error: "Call to a member function current() on a non-object". url() returns a string, not an object, so i dont think this could ever have worked. Perhaps you were thinking about some other method or object, instead of url()?

Comment: Nah, I use this on daily basis. Check [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url)

Comment: I see. This only works in **version 5.2 or greater**. But its quite nice.

Answer (score 23):

In laravel 7 or 8 use helper function

> ```
> Get Current Route Name
> ```

```
request()->route()->getName()
```

> To check if route is current better to create your own method for request class using macro

In `AppServiceProvider` In `boot` method :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
public function boot()
    {
        Request::macro('isCurrentRoute', function ($routeNames) {
            $bool = false;
            foreach (is_array($routeNames) ? $routeNames : explode(",",$routeNames) as $name) {
               if(request()->routeIs($name)) {
                   $bool = true;
                   break;
                }
             }

             return $bool;
        });
    }
```

> You can used this method in blade or controller

```
request()->isCurrentRoute('foo') // string route
request()->isCurrentRoute(['bar','foo','xyz.*']) //array routes
request()->isCurrentRoute('blogs,foo,bar,xyz.*') //string route seperated by comma
```

> You can use inbuilt laravel route method

```
request()->routeIs('home');
request()->routeIs('blogs.*'); //using wildcard
```

Comment: It should be `request()->routeIs('home')` in this instance to check route name or `request()->is('home')`.  The latter `Determines if the current request URI matches a pattern`, while the former `Determines if the route name matches a given pattern`.  So the former `routeIs` method I would suggest.  Definitely not `route()->is('home')`.  You will receive no such method error or `route()` method expecting 1 argument 0 given. [Source][ https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html ]

Answer (score 15):

Laravel 5.2 You can use

```
$request->route()->getName()
```

It will give you current route name.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. the `name()` method will add or change the name, while the `getName()` method returns it.

Answer (score 15):

In 5.2, you can use the request directly with:

```
$request->route()->getName();
```

or via the helper method:

```
request()->route()->getName();
```

Output example:

```
"home.index"
```

Answer (score 9):

**Accessing The Current Route**

Get current route name in Blade templates

```
{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}
```

for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Answer (score 6):

Shortest way is Route facade
`\Route::current()->getName()`

This also works in laravel 5.4.*

Answer (score 5):

In a controller action, you could just do:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $routeName = $request->route()->getName();
}
```

`$request` here is resolved by Laravel's service container.

`getName()` returns the route name for [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes) only, `null` otherwise (but you could still explore the `\Illuminate\Routing\Route` object for something else of interest).

In other words, you should have your route defined like this to have "nameOfMyRoute" returned:

```
Route::get('my/some-action', [
    'as' => 'nameOfMyRoute',
    'uses' => 'MyController@someAction'
]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use in template:

```
<?php $path = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath(); ?>
<?php if (starts_with($path, 'admin/')) echo "active"; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the most easiest solution is using this helper:

```
request()->route()->getName()
```

For the docs, see [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-request)

Comment: I think it is better choice in blade.

Answer (score 5):

You can use bellow code to get route name in blade file

```
request()->route()->uri
```

Answer (score 4):

`Request::path();` is better, and remember to `use Request;`

Answer (score 4):

Now in Laravel `5.3` I am seeing that can be made similarly you tried:

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Answer (score 4):

**Accessing The Current Route(v5.3 onwards)**

You may use the current, currentRouteName, and currentRouteAction methods on the Route facade to access information about the route handling the incoming request:

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

Refer to the API documentation for both the underlying class of the Route facade and Route instance to review all accessible methods.

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Answer (score 3):

```
$request->route()->getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

first thing you may do is import **namespace** on the top of **class**.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

**laravel v8**

```
$route = Route::current(); // Illuminate\Routing\Route
$name = Route::currentRouteName(); // RouteName
$action = Route::currentRouteAction(); // Action
```

**Laravel v7,6 and 5.8**

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

Answer (score 3):

**use laravel helper and magic methods**

```
request()->route()->getName()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php` you can use the method `currentRouteNamed()` by injecting a Router in your controller method. For example:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
public function index(Request $request, Router $router) {
   return view($router->currentRouteNamed('foo') ? 'view1' : 'view2');
}
```

or using the Route facade:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
   return view(\Route::currentRouteNamed('foo') ? 'view1' : 'view2');
}
```

You could also use the method `is()` to check if the route is named any of the given parameters, but beware this method uses `preg_match()` and I've experienced it to cause strange behaviour with dotted route names (like `'foo.bar.done'`). There is also the matter of performance around `preg_match()` 
 which is a big subject in the PHP community.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    return view(\Route::is('foo', 'bar') ? 'view1' : 'view2');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to memorize anything, when you would like some variable of Request, by `dd(request())` can assess which variable is prominent for you.
In the below image, it is clear.
[image]

So, if you would like to get the path, obviously, this code will show

```
dd(request()->getpathInfo())
```

don't forget to embed
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
For instance:

```
if(request()->getpathInfo()=="/logadmin"){
do somethings....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Helper file,

Your can use `Route::current()->uri()` to get current URL.

Hence, If you compare your route name to set active class on menu then it would be good if you use

`Route::currentRouteName()` to get the name of route and compare

Answer (score 1):

I have used for getting route name in larvel 5.3

`Request::path()`

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
$routeArray = app('request')->route()->getAction();
$controllerAction = class_basename($routeArray['controller']);
list($controller, $route) = explode('@', $controllerAction);
echo $route;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method :

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

In Laravel version > 6.0, You can use below methods:

```
$route = Route::current();

$name = Route::currentRouteName();

$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

Comment: Gettings error: Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::current()

Answer (score 1):

**Accesing the Current Route Name in Controller**

ie - http://localhost/your_project_name/edit

```
$request->segment(1);  // edit
```

( or )

```
$request->url();  // http://localhost/your_project_name/edit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\Request::path()
```

I use this to get current uri

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i use, i don't know why no one mentioned it, because it worked perfectly fine for me.

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri ; // this returns a string like '/home'
```

So i use it in my `master.blade.php` file :

```
...

@if ( Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri =='/dashbord' )
   @include('navbar')
@endif
...
```

witch really helped me re use the same views without duplicating code.

Answer (score 1):

use helper:

```php
app('request')->route()->getName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
url()->current();
```

*it will result **http://localhost:8000/your-path/...***

Answer (score 0):

for some reasons, I couldn't use any of these solutions. so I just declared my route in `web.php` as `$router->get('/api/v1/users', ['as' => 'index',   'uses' => 'UserController@index'])` and in my controller I got the name of the route using `$routeName =  $request->route()[1]['as'];` which `$request` is `\Illuminate\Http\Request $request` typehinted parameter in `index` method of `UserController`

using Lumen 5.6. Hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this line of code : `url()->current()`

In blade file : `{{url()->current()}}`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do that. You can type:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::route()->getName()
```

To get route name.

Answer (score 0):

no one have answer if route name or url id needed on view direct
for the route name on view direct

```
$routeName = Request::route()->getName();
```

for the id from url on view

```
$url_id = Request::segment(2);
```