# Getting the route detail by name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to get the details of a route by it's name like the controller and action name that it uses?

I went through the [documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html) and it only has such functionality listed for the current route i.e. `current()`, `currentRouteAction()` etc. Is it possible to get the detail of a route, **action and controller** to be specific, by it's alias/name?

Comment: maybe this anwer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5/30052319#30052319

Comment: Nope, because everything there is related to the **current route** but what I want is not the current but a specific route by it's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can get it in this way

`Route::getRoutes()->getByName($name);`

or

`Route::getRoutes()->getByAction($action);`