# Call to a member function getName() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i am modifying a custom 404 page which is already in views-> errors folder.
the problem is when i extend the master layout then it is showing an error

```
Call to a member function getName() on a non-object
```

at "Route::current()->getName()=='home'"

```
<nav class="pmh-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
              <a class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-typography--text-uppercase <?php echo (Route::current()->getName()=='home')?'active':'' ?>" href="{{URL::route('home')}}">Home</a>
              <a class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-typography--text-uppercase <?php echo (Route::current()->getName()=='blog')?'active':'' ?>" href="{{URL::route('blog')}}">Blog</a>
              <a class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-typography--text-uppercase <?php echo (Route::current()->getName()=='about-us')?'active':'' ?>" href="{{URL::route('about-us')}}">About</a>
              <a class="mdl-navigation__link mdl-typography--text-uppercase <?php echo (Route::current()->getName()=='contact')?'active':'' ?>" href="{{ URL::route('contact') }}">Contact</a>
          </nav>
```

what i am doing wrong? Please help me...

Comment: `Route::current()` isn't returning an object...

Comment: since i do not want to remove this code as it is applicable to all views.. just for 404 page it has to be another solutions...

Comment: Which version of laravel ?

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5 .

Comment: the version of laravel is 5.1

Comment: thanks Amit Ray ... but can i use isset() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->path();
```

just try this

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: the $request->path() return the current action name
i'm using this in a function($request){}