# Laravel get Route parameters outside controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have defined a dummy route like this:

```
Route::get('sth/{v1}/{v2}' , [
    'uses'=>'SthController@sth',
]) ;
```

how can I get the value of **v1** and **v2**, outside controllers?

Comment: Such as...where? In the route file, in a service provider, in middleware...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current route name in laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use this code

```
$current_params = Route::current()->parameters();

dd($current_params->v1) ;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get the values of **v1** and **v2** anywhere like this:

```
request()->v1;
request()->v2;
```

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.6 for me it was:

```
Route::current()->parameters['v1']
Route::current()->parameters['v2']
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the laravel helper named: request()

```
$value = request('key', $default);
```

For your route you can use

```
$v1 = request('v1','default data');
$v2 = request('v2','default data');
```

Laravel documentation: [request helper laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-request)

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried but think its `Route::current()`, use from anywhere to access the parameters

```
$currentParams = Route::current()->parameters();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the data in session in controller when pass, then from anywhere you can get your desire data,

```
Session::put('v1');
Session::put('v2');
```

now anywhere you can access like:

```
Session::get('v1')
Session::get('v2')
```

if you  need to delete session data just use

```
Session::forget('v1')
Session::forget('v2')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be alternative way:

`Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('v1')`