# Writing JS code in blade templating engine

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a `Laravel 5.0` project and inside of that I have a `foo.blade.php` file,in here I want to use some `Javascript` to get the pathname of the link the user currently in like so

```
window.location.pathname
```

Is it possible? Or blade templating allows only `php` to be written on the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Javascript runs client side, so whatever you write in `<script>` tag will be totally ignored by laravel.

But if you want to access path (route) in laravel, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5).