# How to change different header for various pages in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need call different header for hosting and about pages mentioned below, while executing the below code I'm getting error as "Undefined class constant 'hosting'". suggest me how to solve this and call different headers for various pages.

```
@if(Route::hosting == 'hosting')
{
  @include('partials.header');
}
@elseif(Route::About == 'About'){
   @include('partials.header1');
}
 @endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\Request::is()` to check current route, and dont' use `{...}` inside `@if` condition, if there is only two condition `@if...@else...@endif` is enough.

```
@if(\Request::is("hosting"))
  @include('partials.header');
@else
   @include('partials.header1');
@endif
```

**You can also avoid of using another header** `partials.header1`, If there is not much difference.

Pass a variable named `is_hosting` as `true/false` and display contents accordingly..

```
@if(\Request::is("hosting"))
  @include('partials.header',["is_hosting"=>true]);
@else
  @include('partials.header',["is_hosting"=>false]);
@endif
```

Inside `partials.header`

```
@if(isset($is_hosting) && $is_hosting) 
    header's content
@else
    header1's content
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'hosting') 

    @include('partials.header');

@elseif(Route::currentRouteName() == 'About')

     @include('partials.header1'); 

@endif
```

use `Route::currentRouteName()` to get the name of the current route.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:

[How to get current route name in laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5)

I believe your're confusing how to access the current route name. There's a couple of methods available to access the current route:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();  // Route path
Request::route()->getName();  // Route Name
$request->path();  // URL
```