# Laravel route without prefix name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to utilize the Laravel landing page route. For example Laravel takes you to the welcome page by default, and it has no url text after the slash.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

In my welcome page I'm using following condition to apply styling based on the route name.

```
{!! Route::is('/')? 'class="index"':'' !!}
```

However this code doesn't work. How can I check the route of the welcome page properly?

Edit: Using "Request" instead of "Route" makes it work. However for consistency's sake I would like to know if it can be done using "Route" too.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your route and use this name to condition your styling

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
```

In your blade

```
{!! (Route::currentRouteName() == 'home')? 'class="index"':'' !!}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@if(Request::is('/'))
  class="index"
@endif
```

or more simply

```
if(Request::is('/')) {
   class="index"
}
```

Comment: it will not make any differnece

Comment: yes both are similar in terms of output but first one is blade template code and the second one is PHP code,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<li class="@if (request()->is('/')) index @endif"></li>
    // ...
</li>
```

You can use wildcards as well with this:

```
<li class="@if (request()->is('/some-url/*')) active @endif">
    // ...
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<li {!! Request::is('/') ? 'class=index' : '' !!}>...</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
```

in blade

```
class = "default class @if(\Request::route()->getName() == 'home')your_class @endif"
```

Comment: \Request::route()->getName()  return current  route name