# Set class active on click navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

I need help setting a link as active upon clicking on my html top nav bar.

The nav bar looks like this

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
          <a href="{{route('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Clients <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ route('add.consumer') }}">Add New Client</a></li></i></a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

So when i click Home it must highlight Home when i click on Clients it must highlight Clients. I really don't know how to achieve this so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your Javascript.

Comment: Given that you have `<a href='...` so that clicking your nav bar will redirect, just add `class='active'` to the current page's tab when you render the nav bar

Comment: you cann using js or php in laravel see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name

Answer (score 0):

```js
// when any a link click
$('a').click(function(){
    // if already any element in active status remove it
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    // add active status to this one only
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
})
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
          <a href="{{route('home')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Clients <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ route('add.consumer') }}">Add New Client</a></li></i></a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting via JS is pretty pointless, since as soon as it redirects and loads the new page, that setting will be forgotten. What you want to do is have PHP check your current route, and assign a `class` based on that. This can be done via the `request()->is()` check:

If navigating to `myapp.com/home`, use the following:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('home') ? 'active': '' }}">
  <a href="{{ route('home') }}">
    Home
    @if(request()->is('home'))
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    @endif
  </a>
<li>
```

This demonstrates how to use via a ternary operator (best used for in-line statements) and the `@if()@endif` blade syntax. Just ensure your `is()` check is matching your route, so `->is("")` for `Route::get("/", ...);`, etc. etc. and PHP will automatically assign the `active` class and `(current)` SR element.

Note; there is likely a way to handle this for named routes (like `route('home')`), but I haven't used named routes much, so I'm not positive on that. Also, might be best to assign the result of `request()->is('home')` to a variable to avoid repeating code.

Comment: This is perfect :-) thank you so much for this. been struggling for a while.

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped, please consider upvoting/accepting as answer. Cheers!