# login page in two places. for each other redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I make an online store in which I have two login places. /checkout (in cart) and /login. 
  
Can i do it in the existing method to make redirect look like this? 
if i login in /checkout ->redirect('/checkout'). 
(for loggin in /login) it stays like it is /redirect('/')

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve that by using the `redirectTo()` method in the Login Controller and checking which route is sending the request through the `path()` method. You have to name the routes for it to work though. So in your login Controller you'll have this;

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

protected function redirectTo(){
    if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'login'){
        return '/';
    }else if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'checkout'){
        return '/checkout';
    }

}
```

more info on how to get the route name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name)

and info on the `redirectTo()` function [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Try it out, tell me what happens..

Comment: Unfortunately, your idea didn't work. in the comment I placed the solution that I used

Comment: I saw your answer, I feel like the use of `strpos()` is not robust but hey, if it works, it works..

Answer (score 0):

only this solution works:

```
protected function redirectTo() {
    if(strpos(URL::previous(), 'checkout')) {
        return '/checkout';
    } elseif(strpos(URL::previous(), 'login')) {
        return '/';
    }
}
```