# Laravel: How do I get the current route

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get the route a user is currently at? I need that to hide a navbar link if a user is currently at the route that link leads to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: How to Get Current Route Name? (v5 & v6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/laravel-how-to-get-current-route-name-v5-v6)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try searching before posting a new question, there are many duplicates of this here already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the current, currentRouteName, and currentRouteAction methods to access information about the route handling the incoming request:

```
$route = Route::current();
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
$action = Route::currentRouteAction();
```

You can check this [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#accessing-the-current-route) too

Hope it helps...